# in my men's category, other category product is showing i only assign 6 products but i don't knw why 40 product is showing

Tags: magento-1.9, category, adminhtml, indexing

In my men category, other category product is showing i only assign 6 products but i don't knew why 40 product is showing here please help me.
i only assign 6 product to this category i checked from menu and product function but i didn't find any solution for this.

Let's assume I have a category, Clothing and this category have a sub-category, T-shirts.

Now I add a product to the T-shirts category (by checking the box in the add product screen), but I don't check the Clothing category. So, I assumed this meant that the product would only appear in the T-shirts category on the front end, and not in the Clothing parent category.

However, the product appears in the Clothing and T-shirt categories.

This is a problem because the T-shirt category is an "`Include in navigation menu" > No category`, i.e. It is supposed to be hidden. All the products in the category have visibility of catalog, so they don't appear in search results.

I've investigated this quite deeply so far and have found that the problem is with the Magento catalog indexing. Running the Category Products indexer from `System > Index Management` rebuilds the index, running `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Indexer_Product::reindexAll()`.

This function SELECTs various data from several category-related tables and pipes it into the `catalog_category_product_index` table, which is the table used to generate the products collection for the category pages.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to hide/prevent products from sub-categories appearing in their parent categories?

Answer (score 0):

On the category edit page, **Display Settings** tab, set **Is Anchor** to "No".

Info about anchor categories: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/navigation-layered-anchor-categories.html.